# How to add marginal histogram to a categorical values plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a categorical plot, where y-value is a username, and  x-value is a time stamp `YYYY-MM-DD H:M`. Image below gives you an idea (please, note a hundred or so points were plotted).
[image: x-axis is time]

I decreased alpha value, so that darker regions are ones with more datapoints and light regions have fewer datapoints. Still, it doesn't give me a good idea where most of points are concentrated.

**Question:** Is it possible to add a marginal density plot or a histogram to this type of a categorical plot?

Thank you!

**Minimal example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Data:
source_data = [("user_1", "2023-11-24 10:30:00"), ("user_1", "2023-11-24 10:15:00"),
("user_1", "2023-11-24 09:55:00"), ("user_1", "2023-11-24 22:10:00"),
("user_1", "2023-11-24 15:55:00"), ("user_1", "2023-11-24 11:15:00"),
("user_1", "2023-11-24 09:30:00"), ("user_1", "2023-11-24 22:25:00"),
("user_1", "2023-11-24 17:20:00"), ("user_1", "2023-11-24 23:55:00")]

# Convert the list into the data frame; convert strings into time:
df = pd.DataFrame(source_data, columns=['user', 'time'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
ax.scatter(x=df['time'], y=df['user'], marker='.', color='b')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0, 24, 1)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M hr'))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens if you have multiple users?

Comment: Well, I will have to think how to create a dot plot and a histogram for each user. But I do not want to ask too many questions in one post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) to do with [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html):

```
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='time', y='user', hue='user', kind='violin', inner=None, legend=False)
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='time', y='user', size=3, color='black')
```

Output:
[image]

As alternative, you can also use [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html):

```
uid = df['user'].astype('category').cat.codes.rename('user')
g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='time', y=uid, hue='user')
ax = g.ax_joint  # to get axis
```

But you have to fix `yaxis` to have user labels:
[image]

Comment: @user136555. Does it solve your problem?